# How to sign out or disable an xbox that won't turn on?

Tags: xbox-one

My Xbox One X suddenly started turning off as soon as I turn it on.  I hit the xbox button, hear the "Beedledeep" sound, then a second later it turns off.  Its out of warranty and I don't want to pay $200 to fix a $150 console, and I prob don't have the chops to open it up and troubleshoot it myself.

So, is there some way I can simply deactivate it or somehow safeguard my account so that I can sell it for parts?  I think I had it set to auto sign-in on boot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can login to your xbox live account, change your password and then do a 'logout everywhere'. Not at home at the moment but I'm pretty sure I remember doing this at some time in the past

Comment: https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/account-profile/signin-security/how-to-sign-out

Comment: would there still be some personal info on the console?  just would protect from additional purchases, info gathering?

Comment: I think this would render your account inaccessible from the console. the console would not be able to login in if you have changed the account password

Answer (score 0):

A quote from Microsoft website
"Remove a device
If you don't use a device but it still appears in your devices, here's how to remove it:

Go to account.microsoft.com/devices, sign in, and find the device you want to remove.

Select the device to see all your options, select Remove device, then follow the instructions."

Basically you go to the Microsoft link I posted above. Sing into your account and it will list all the devices connected to your account.  Just select the Xbox you want to remove and accept.

Also, an easy way was posted above mine, in that you can just changed your Microsoft password and it will ask u to sign out of all devices.   And even if u don't sign out of all devices, the next time your Xbox is booted it, it will still ask u to enter your password again.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the link that you are citing so others can confirm this.